# Quick MySQL query question

Tags: mysql, compare, sql-update

I have two tables, both have the same columns. We will call them `tilistings` and `tilistings_temp`

Two columns in `tilistings_temp`, `lat` and `lng` are geocoded with Google API. `tilistings` has these same two columns, but they are empty. `tilistings` may contain some rows that are not in `tilistings_temp`, and vise versa.

Every night, `tilistings` is imported from a 3rd party I do not want to have to geocode the existing 2500 coordinates that are in `tilistings_temp` so my question is how do I compare the two tables and:

Set the values of `lat` and `lng` in `tilistings` to the corresponding values from `tilistings_temp` (both tables have `mlsid` in common)

Is it:

```
UPDATE tilistings
SET lat = tilistings_temp.lat, lng = tilistings_temp.lng
WHERE mlsid = tilistings_temp.mlsid;
```

??? Sorry for asking if this is right, I just can not risk corrupting the data inside the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update join might be quicker and its certainly less ugly than a double sub-query.

```
UPDATE tilistings a
    JOIN tilistings_temp b USING (mlsid)
SET a.lat = b.lat, a.lng = b.lng;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update tilistings a
set (a.lat,a.lng) = (
    select b.lat,b.lng
    from tilistings_temp b
    where b.mlsid = a.mlsid
);
```

EDIT: Just tried it and MySQL can't (yet?) understand compound attribute update like Oracle, so it gets a little uglier and likely slower when done via MySQL

```
update tilistings a
set a.lat = (
    select b.lat
    from tilistings_temp b
    where b.mlsid = a.mlsid
) , a.lng = (
    select c.lng
    from tilistings_temp c
    where c.mlsid = a.mlsid
);
```

Comment: It was a 45 second query on 1800 rows but it worked...It will suffice, this script is ran as a cron job at 3AM and its much faster than geocoding...thanks

Comment: Just to make sure, you do have an index on the tilistings_temp.mlsid attribute, yes?  If not, make sure you do so it doesn't have to scan.